# Why can't I execute `following-char` using `execute-extended-command`?

Tags: emacs

I'm trying to write a few short elisp functions to transform some text. I'd like to test out small pieces of each function as I write them to help me understand how each bit works, and ensure it functions as expected. To do this, I type `M-x`, then the name of the function. This works for some functions (e.g. `evil-forward-WORD-begin`) but not others (e.g. `following-char`).

I've worked around the issue by using `C-x C-e` to execute the s-expressions from my buffer, but why can't `following-char` can't be executed via `execute-extended-command`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/29199807/1030675

Comment: Definitely a duplicate. Thanks for the link!